# Play multi-field validation

Tags: playframework

I am sure this is a no-brainer for Play-gurus, but I have found no way.

I have a class with two fields representing the whole and decimal part of a monetary value :

```
@Required
@Min(0)
private Integer whole;

@Range(min = 0, max = 99)
private Integer decimal;
```

Now, I do not want to allow a value where both whole and decimal part are 0.

Can I specify this using annotations ? And if not, where do I hook in my validation code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm no guru but I think you can achieve what you want by defining a custom check:

```
@CheckWith(WholeCheck.class)
private Integer whole;

@CheckWith(DecCheck.class)
private Integer decimal;

    static class WholeCheck extends Check {
        public boolean isSatisfied(Object obj, Object whole) {
            boolean satisfied = true;
            MyObj myobj = (MyObj) obj;
            if(((Integer)whole) == 0 && myobj.decimal ==0){
                satisfied = false;
                setMessage("whole and decimal cannot be 0");
            }

            return satisfied;
        }
    }
```